# JavaScript regex to match items in a stringified array that don't contain a search term

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I want to remove all span items that don't contain the string 'foo' from a stringified array. The string looks like this:

```
["<span>This is some text</span>","<span>This is more foo</span>","
<span><span>Inner span blah</span>This is one has an inner span
 foo</span>","<span>Last one</span>"]
```

The end result string should look like this:

```
["<span>This is more foo</span>","<span><span>Inner span blah</span>
This is one has an inner span foo</span>"]
```

Creating an array with `JSON.parse()` and then filtering works, but it isn't fast enough for my purposes.

I've tried regular expression variants with negative lookahead, but can't seem to get them to work.

Comment: So it's not an array, it's a string, and parsing it is too slow?

Comment: Yes, it's a string – realised it's a bit ambiguous the way I described it. I've added some text that hopefully makes it clearer.

Comment: If you're worried about performance, regex might not work either. You could loop over the string, keeping track of what spans you're in and adding them to your final string once you reach the close tag at nesting level 0. If that made sense.

Comment: Simple syntax analyzer helps you. Look continuous for start array item, "foo", end item then cut item if "foo" not found

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I seem to have got this to work: ` var nonMatchingItems = new RegExp('"<span((?!' + searchTerm + ').)*?<\/span>"', 'gmi');`

Comment: Why not just loop through the array and test each entry against this regex: `/\bfoo\b/g` ?

Comment: This doesn't make sense: "Creating an array with JSON.parse() and then filtering works, but it isn't fast enough for my purposes. I've tried regular expression variants". A regex 99% of the time is slower than using a build in function.

Comment: @PedroLobito Building an array from the string using `JSON.parse`, then filtering (which requires testing each span), seems to be slower than using a regex on a string, like the one in my comment above. Potentially I have to run this over several thousand documents (from a CouchDB database), each of which may have several thousand spans. I'll build a comparison on jsPerf to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript provide functions to achieve what you want, using a regex will spare unnecessary resources.

**Code:**

```
var myArray = ["<span>This is some text</span>","<span>This is more foo</span>","<span><span>Inner span blah</span>This is one has an inner span foo</span>","<span>Last one</span>"];

for (i=0;i<myArray.length;++i) {
  if(myArray[i].indexOf("foo") === -1){
    myArray.splice([i], 1);
  }
};
console.log(myArray);
```

**Outputs:**

```
["<span>This is more foo</span>", "<span><span>Inner span b...n inner span foo</span>"]
```

### [CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/tuga/pen/yNBoKr)

**Explanation :**

Loop `myArray`:

```
for (i=0;i<myArray.length;++i)
```

Check if `foo` isn't present using [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
if(myArray[i].indexOf("foo") === -1)
```

If `foo` isn't present, remove it from array using [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
myArray.splice([i], 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer! This doesn't provide a regex, but it's so well done I'll accept it.  I did try something similar, as I mentioned in my question. Converting to an array, filtering, then converting back to a string seemed to be slower than just using a regex on the string.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like.

```
var array = ["<span>This is some text</span>","<span>This is more foo</span>","
<span><span>Inner span blah</span>This is one has an inner span
 foo</span>","<span>Last one</span>"];

for (var item in array) {
  var value = array[item];
  if(value.indexOf('foo') < 0) {
    array.splice(item, 1)
  }
}
```

Explanation:
First you initialise the an `array` with all your strings.
Using a `for in` loop you iterate over that array.
And every time you find the word `foo` you remove the current element from the array.

Comment: Thanks for providing an array version.